# SIMPLE XML - How to parse successfully even if feed has "changed" and new attributes have been added?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, attributes, simple-framework, strict

I've been working on an app that parses out the information available in the following feed:

http://www.tsn.ca/datafiles/xml/cfl/boxscores/1191818.xml

Everything was working fine until today. The feed changed to add in the TT attribute for some players...

```
<box-player table="receiving-data" team="1" name="Jeff|Fuller" REC="1" TT="0" YDS="21" TD="0" LNG="21">player</box-player>
```

and then simple started throwing TT is not specified or Attribute not listed exceptions( can't remember the "actual" name).

I made sure to add **strict = false**, for the root of the feed:

```
@Root(name = "boxscore", strict = false)
public class Boxscore 
{
   @Element(name = "file-info", required = false)
   private FileInfo fi;

   @Element(name = "away-team", required = false)
   private AwayTeam awayTeam;

   @Element(name = "home-team", required = false)
   private HomeTeam homeTeam;

   @Element(name = "stat-headings", required = false)
   private StatHeadings statHeadings;

   @Element(name = "qips", required = false)
   private Qips qips;

   @Element (name = "notes", required = false)
   private String notes;

   @ElementList(name = "players", required = false)
   private List<Player> anyPlayers;

   @ElementList(inline = true, required=false, entry = "box-player")
   private List<Player> inlinePlayers;

   public List<Player> getPlayers()
   {
    if(anyPlayers == null)
    {
        return inlinePlayers;
    }
    else return anyPlayers;
   }
   // other get methods ...
}
```

My declaration for the player class looks like - Here's an excerpt:

```
@Element(name= "box-player")
public class Player { ... }
```

I have tried to add strict = false for the @Element, but I get "The attribute strict is undefined for the annotation type Element".

**Is there a way I can ignore newly added attributes? So parsing still works?**

Comment: Thanks for the edit IMSoP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `@Root(strict=false)` to the `Player` class. What's happening is that the `Boxscore` class is not `strict` but the `Player` class is.

Also, the [documentation](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/Root.) states that: Also, elements within an element list, as represented by the ElementList annotation need this annotation so that the element names can be determined.

Since your `Player` class is in an `ElementList` it needs the `@Root` annotation as well.

Comment: It is strange that it works without the @Root annotation though.. I changed it so that its @Root(name = "box-player", strict= false), but I had @Element(name = "box-player", required = false) before, and until the new TT attribute was added, I didn't even know it would be a problem later.

For some reason I assumed that the strict annotation would be somehow carried to all the children classes ...